# How do I network, and connect people in a node.js social app?

Tags: javascript, backend, mern

I just started a social web app for fun, using MERN stack (Mongo, Express, React, Node.js) + GraphQL, Apollo. Most of the part is clear, from tutorials, however, I couldn't find anything about, how to build the logic for actual networking, with that said: follow each other, and so doing see each others feed, hiding others and similar features. 
My question is how do I find something about this topic, and what is your recommendation, and best practices? 
(It's not a production app, but I would make a bigger project to roll up all my knowledge, and experience, show off in my portfolio)

Comment: so it's like...everything is working perfectly locally on your computer?

Comment: No, I am not there yet, its under development, but I would add this key feature, and build the app around it.

Comment: mind showing the tutorial you are following?

Comment: I've done a quite few, React from Wes Bos, GrapQL + React from Netninja, Node.js and the current Full stack is from Brad Traversy. Good stuff, but I am afraid my particular question is not covered, so would be nice to find one for that.